# Freeing void pointer array, crashes after freeing first element

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I have such simple program, that wraps a `void*` array into a struct with length and with automatic resize. Although it crashes after I free first element.

[Gif that illustrates my problem](http://recordit.co/4mTedaLB4N)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "array.h"
#include "error_handler.h"

#define RESIZE_STEP 3

Array * new_array(int initial_length, size_t size_of_element)
{
    Array* temp_struct = NULL;
    temp_struct = (Array*)malloc(sizeof(Array));
    void** temp_array = NULL;
    temp_array = (void**)malloc(initial_length * size_of_element);
    if (!temp_array) {
        if (print_message(MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR) == BREAK)
        {
            deallocate_tab(temp_struct);
            temp_array = NULL;
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < initial_length; i++) {
        temp_array[i] = malloc(size_of_element);
        if (!temp_array[i] && print_message(MEMORY_ALLOCATION_ERROR) == BREAK) {
            deallocate_tab(temp_struct);
            temp_array = NULL;
            exit(1);
        }
        else {
            temp_array[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    temp_struct->array = temp_array;
    temp_struct->length = 0;
    temp_struct->max_length = initial_length;

    return temp_struct;

}

Array * deallocate_tab(Array * vector)
{
    if (vector) {
        void** tab = vector->array;
        if (tab)
        {
            int M = _msize(tab) / sizeof(void *);  //ilosc wierszy w macierzy str
            for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
            {
                if (tab[i])
                {
                    free(tab[i]);
                    tab[i] = NULL;
                }
            }

            free(tab);
            tab = NULL;
        }
        free(vector);
        vector = NULL;
    }
    return vector;
}
```

The first iteration of freeing loop goes smoothly and in Debuger I can read my value, but after freeing first item in the array every other item seems to be nonexistant and I can look them up.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Why is this tagged for two different languages?  Pick one!

Comment: For these types of issues, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is your friend.

Comment: @Olaf Not that the problem is basically same in both of them.. Not like C++ is backwards compatibile...

Comment: @Haito - It isn't "backwards compatible". It never was. Just try to compile this legal line in C `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` with a C++ compiler. Go on, tell us how "backwards compatible" it is.

Comment: @Haito what do you mean backward compatible? Do you intend to hint that C++ is a newer version of C? Don't say that here please. You will have a bad time.

Comment: @Haito: C++ is **not** backwards compatible with C! Whoever told you does not know at least one of the languages well enough to write much more that a simple "Hello World" program. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics! And don't cast `void *` in C!

Comment: @Olaf You are right/ My bad.

Comment: Note to OP, do not cast the result of your `alloc`'s

Comment: so, you don't suppose the definition of `Array` might be pertinent at all?

Comment: `int M = _msize(tab) / sizeof(void *);` --> `int M = vector->length;`

Comment: To explain more on @BLUEPIXY's comment - malloc may allocate more space than what is requested (for padding, book keeping etc). So _msize(tab) returns more than what you had allocated. As a result your loop runs more than it should have. Freeing unallocated pointer causes it to crash.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya that wasn't the case really. I have requested 8 elems and 8 were allocated. The problem I have is that Loop on first iteration free's everything and on second iteration it crashes...

Comment: Its all very well and nice to allocate the space for an array of `void *`...  Were you planning on setting them all to `NULL` at some point?

Comment: @infixed Yes, I know about that. That's why I have that if(elem) thing to check whether item is null

Comment: @Haito you created an array of your final elements but treated them as an array of pointers to the individual elements.

Comment: Yes, you check it on freeing them.  but after the `malloc` the memory may be non-zero, i.e not `nullptr`.  (I suppose some versions of malloc could zero things but...).  The safe thing to do would be to set all those pointers to `nullptr` right after you malloc the array

Answer (score 0):

In c there is no way to determine the size of an array simply by looking at it. ie this will not work

```
int M = _msize(tab) / sizeof(void *);
```

You need to pass the size around as well as a pointer to its base

Comment: use valgrind (as others said)

Comment: Does valgrind run on windows though